# Authenticate gcloud service account in automated fashion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil

### Overall objective:

We want to be able to upload artifacts from with a Docker container in our Circle CI jobs to a bucket in Google Cloud. Ideally, we'd be able to accomplish this with `gsutil cp <artifact> <bucket>`

### The issue:

I'm having the hardest time authenticating a `gcloud` service account in an automated fashion, and I cannot find documentation for this anywhere. Just about every article I've read has you following one of these two variants:

1. Configuring with `gsutil`

   ```
   $ gsutil config -a
   ```

   However, this prompts a series of questions that require interaction with the shell:

   ```
   Backing up existing config file "/Users/<user>/.boto" to "/Users/<user>/.boto.bak"...
   This command will create a boto config file at
   /Users/<user>/.boto containing your credentials, based on your
   responses to the following questions.
   What is your google access key ID?
   ```
2. Logging in with `gcloud`:

   ```
   $ gcloud auth login
   Your browser has been opened to visit:

       https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?....
   ```

As the end outcome here is that a Docker container would be authenticating a service account to perform `gsutil cp`, the interactive sign-in is not very favorable...

I have the credentials JSON setup in [this example](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production), but setting the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` *still* prompts a `Are you sure? [Y/n]` message that cannot be bypassed automatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command to configure the Google Cloud SDK CLI from service account Json file:

`gcloud auth activate-service-account test@development-123456.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=service_account.json`

Replace the email address `test@...` with your service account email address.
Replace the Json filename `service_account.json` with the filename that you are using for your service account credentials.

The service account email address is inside the service account json file as `client_email`.

If you would like more information I wrote a number of articles on Google Credentials and OAuth:

[Google Cloud – Setting up Gcloud with Service Account Credentials](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-setting-up-gcloud-with-service-account-credentials/)

Comment: Thank you! I looked all over for exactly this

Comment: For future reference, here are a couple of official documentation pages related to this: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing#authorizing_with_a_service_account https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account